# Snap Framework: How do I run IO within a handler

Tags: haskell, monads, haskell-snap-framework

this is probably a simple question and I've seen a similar one on SO, but I'm still stuck.

I'm trying to do an HTTP call to pull in the contents of another blog and display it on my page.  This is more of a learning exercise than anything.

Here's my handler

```
blog :: App1Handler ()
blog = do
  contents <- Requester.getUrl "http://someblog.com/"
  heistLocal (bindString "contents" contents) . render $ "blog"
```

Requester.getUrl has the signature  getUrl :: String -> IO T.Text

And the error I get back is

> src/Main.hs:50:15:
>      Couldn't match expected type `Handler App1 App1 t0' with actual type`IO T.Text'
>      In the return type of a call of `getUrl'
>      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
>        contents <- getUrl "http://someblog.com/"
>      In the expression:
>        do { contents <- getUrl "http://someblog.com/";
>             heistLocal (bindString "contents" contents) . render $ "blog" }

From what I gather, I'm stuck inside of the IO monad and it wants the type Handler App1 App1 t0.  I've experimented with sticking liftIO in places, but I'm pretty confused on this one.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming `App1Handler` is a typical monad stack supporting `IO`, it should just be `contents <- liftIO $ Requester.getUrl "http://someblog.com/"`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Well, I'll be.  I was totally confused.  I thought that if contents was type IO(a) then I'd want to lift `heistLocal (bindString "contents")' over it like a functor.  Thanks hammar, I've got some reading to do.  Also, I appreciate all your answers on here - i keep running into questions that you've answered!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to `liftIO` the `IO` action returned by `getUrl`, like this:

```
contents <- liftIO $ Requester.getUrl "http://someblog.com/"
```

The reasoning here is simple. You have a do-block of type `App1Handler ()`, which means that the
right hand side of any `<-` statement within this do-block must have type `App1Handler a`.

However, `getUrl` returns `IO Text`, so you need to a function to convert from
`IO a` to `App1Handler a` which is exactly what `liftIO` does.

```
liftIO :: MonadIO m => IO a -> m a
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much! This stemmed from my misunderstanding that you could have different monads in each line of a do block.